# React API Fetch Not Returning All Data But Does When Indexing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux, components

My problem is I get a list of data inside of my FetchData class buy its a list. I tried indexing the **countries: data.Countries[0]** for example 0 it gave me the values but I want all the data is there a way to do a **foreach on this**?

**Fetch with index on countries: data.Countries[0]**
[image]

**Fetch without index on countries: data.Countries**
[image]

**fetchData.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Countries from './countries';

class FetchData extends Component {
    
    state = {
        loading: true,
        countries: null
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            countries: data.Countries,
            loading: false
        });
    }
     
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loading || !this.state.countries ? ( 
            <div>loading</div>
            ) : (
            <div> 
                <Countries WorldCountries={this.state.countries.Country} /> 
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FetchData;
```

**countries.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 

const Countries = (prop) => {
    return(
    <h1>{prop.Countries}</h1>
    );
}
export default Countries;
```

Comment: You're passing "WorldCountries" as a prop but why in Countries component you are looking for "prop.Countries"?

Comment: @EmadEmami Oh my bad was trying something but i changed it back to prop.WorldCountries.

Answer (score 2):

your images are confusing to me, but if I understood you correctly you need to do following:

```
  // FetchData component
  ...
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loading || !this.state.countries ? ( 
            <div>loading</div>
            ) : (
            <div>
              {
                this.state.countries.map(country =>
                    <Country country={country.Country} />)
              }
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
  }
  ...
  // FetchData component 


  // Country component
  const Countries = ({ country }) => (
    <h1>{country}</h1>
  );
  // Country component
```

Comment: I get an error of TypeError: this.state.countries.map is not a function

Comment: @abdullahalhamidi what do you have in this.state.countries? what do you set to countries data.Countries[0] or data.Countries?

Comment: Multiple lists {"Country":"Albania","CountryCode":"AL","Slug":"albania","NewConfirmed":501,"TotalConfirmed":24206,"NewDeaths":2,"TotalDeaths":559,"NewRecovered":90,"TotalRecovered":12092,"Date":"2020-11-09T21:01:31Z","Premium":{}}

Comment: There are more lists per country

Comment: Oh it worked! I had to change the variable <Countries country={country.Country} />) it was <Countries country={country.Counttry} />) THANKS!